# FadeIn elements with increasing speed (using a delay) inside a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, delay, fadein

I'm attempting to find a formula that will let me fade in elements with increasing speed.

**Problem: Currently the fadeIn speed ramps up too quickly, I'm trying not to have that very fast fadein occur until about half way through the set (which would almost always be below the fold when a user is viewing the page)**

As in, the first couple elements take about half a second or more to fade in, and it gets faster and faster from there. Currently there's about 39 items in the set, although that could grow/shrink to be 30 up to 60. Total event duration should be about 3-4 seconds.

Here's my attempt at it (in a jQuery each-loop):

`i` is the index of the item (e.g. 1 out of 39, 2 out of 39, etc.)

```js
$("div").css("display","none"); //ONLY FOR DEMO
$("div").each(function(i) {
  i = i+1;
  var currRate = Math.pow(i, 1.2) * 100;
  var delayNum = Math.floor(currRate / i * 15) + 200;
  var fadeNum = 400;
  
  if (i < 5) {delayNum = 450 * i;} //Shameful hack
  
  $(this).delay(delayNum).fadeIn(fadeNum);
});
```

```css
div {display:inline-block; width:20px; height:20px; margin: 2px; background:red;} /*ONLY FOR DEMO*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
```

**codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yKvevw**

I had thought about possibly setting the overall duration of the entire event of fading in all items as a constant. I'm also looking at some exponential growth formulas to see if I can figure out what I'm missing here.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific on the behavior that you want? Especially, what do you mean by "faster"? A shorter duration? Then why do you set a constant duration in your `fadeIn()` call? Maybe add a [Gantt chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gantt_chart) that shows the desired behavior?

Comment: What about your current version exactly isn't working as it should (I added a working code snippet to your question so we can all see what your code does, can you describe for this working demo what exactly isn't working as you would like it to)?

Comment: @myfunkyside, I'm trying to find a equation that makes this feel more natural - as in, the first element is relatively slow (maybe ~700ms) and slightly speeds up as it progresses. The problem currently is that it ramps up too quickly in speed - the fadein speed is shortening too quickly. You can see in the example added (thanks @myfunkyside!) how it fades in very rapidly. I'm trying not to have that rapid fadein occur until about half way through the set (which would almost always be below the fold when a user is viewing the page). I could code this based on index I guess tho, just feels dirty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took some puzzling, but I think I found something workable:

```js
$("div").css("display","none"); //ONLY FOR DEMO
$("div").each(function(i) {
  var startdelay=0, basedelay=600, speed=3, accel=0.33, power=1/3, i=i+1, n=$("div").length, delay=basedelay*n/(speed+(speed*(accel*i/n)));
  delay = startdelay + Math.floor(delay*Math.pow(i/n,power)) - Math.floor(delay*Math.pow(1/n,power));
  $(this).delay(delay).fadeIn(400);
});
```

```css
div {display:inline-block; width:20px; height:20px; background:red;} /*ONLY FOR DEMO*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
```

**codepen: [https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PRyJLG](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PRyJLG?editors=0011)**

- I found this site very helpful while figuring out the exact formula:
  [https://www.mathopenref.com/graphfunctions.html](https://www.mathopenref.com/graphfunctions.html?fx=pow(x/3,1/3)&gx=pow(x,1/3)&hx=sqrt(x)&sh=f&xh=1&xl=0&yh=1&yl=0&a=0&b=0&c=0&d=0)

---

Below is one of my previous attempts, I wasn't satisfied with it, but someone may prefer this one over my final solution:

```js
$("div").css("display","none"); //ONLY FOR DEMO
$("div").each(function(i) {
  var maxdelay=600, mindelay=0, i=i+1, n=$("div").length, delay=mindelay;
  for (var j=1; j<=i; ++j) {delay += Math.floor((maxdelay-mindelay) * (1-Math.pow(j/n,3)));}
  $(this).delay(delay).fadeIn(400);
});
```

```css
div {display:inline-block; width:20px; height:20px; background:red;} /*ONLY FOR DEMO*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
```

*codepen: [https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JLLmrb](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JLLmrb?editors=0011)*

Comment: The main answer you provided is perfect - that's the exact pace I was looking for, that slow and yet progressively faster fade in. Nailed it.